# How do I turn on SSL for test server?

Tags: apache2, ssl

I have a LAMP stack running. My the web root is `/var/www`.

So if I go to `http://linux-server/some/page.php` It renders the page located at `/var/www/some/page.php`

If I use `https` I get page not found.

I would like to enable SSL for all pages, so I can view any of these pages using either http or https.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl` has the configuration for an http server. It can be enabled with the command `sudo a2ensite default-ssl`.

You will also need to enable mod ssl.  This can be done with the command `sudo a2enmod ssl`.  This will point you to `/usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz` for directions on configuring SSL and generting a self-signed certificate. it can be viewed with the command `zless  /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz`

Once you have the certificates installed, you can restart apache with the command `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

Comment: Got it working for the default host name but couldn't get it to work with multiple host names.

Comment: Scratch that, got it.

Comment: For 13.10 you don't need to generate & install self-signed certificates. After enabling mod_ssl and default-ssl, there is already an "Ubuntu" certificate.

Comment: @HalilÖzgür I have found Apache2 has always had a default certificate.  The default self-signed certificate often doesn't match the name being published in DNS.  In that case, a new certificate will need to be installed.  Users who want a CA signed certificate will need to install and configure it.

Comment: @BillThor I thought the question is about local test servers or self-signed certificates, where "invalid certificate" warnings can be ignored.

Comment: the directory probably needs to be `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl`

Comment: My only problem was not enable sudo a2ensite default-ssl. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can add it within apache or add it with a proxy (like nginx).  I prefer setting up an SSL proxy locally or remotely in the first place.  This way if I need to install a WAF or IDS later, there are less modifications required.