# Is there a modern and clear tutorial on setting up SSL for localhost / testing use?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, ssl, openssl

Let's say I'm developing a script for login.example.com.  I have absolutely no access to login.example.com, but that page loads a script on assets.example.com (which I have access to).  To test how well my new script works on the production login page, I changed my /etc/hosts to point assets.example.com to my localhost (and set up Apache accordingly).

The only problem now is that the login page loads **https**://assets.example.com/script.js (Again, I have no influence on this!).  So in order for me to test my script, I need to set up a self-signed SSL cert.

I followed the directions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C/certificates-and-security.html

I also tried using the default-ssl to test it to no avail.  I simply constantly get SSL connection error:

```
// Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error. (Chrome)
```

Thanks!

**Update:** Since we're now at 12.04 LTS && 12.10, the tutorial should address these versions.

Comment: Duplicates? http://askubuntu.com/q/122360/6969 http://askubuntu.com/q/24829/6969

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/24829/6969 links to the same URL I listed in the question.  The other one, though, might work.  I'll try that out.

Comment: (Wow, I just realized I typed "&&" in my update. I'll never be able to hide that I'm a programmer.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least on Ubuntu 12.10, it's crazy simple now.

```
sudo a2ensite default-ssl && sudo a2enmod ssl && sudo service apache2 restart
```

That's all.

Try it:

- http:// localhost
- https:// localhost (I can't link these due to restrictions.)
- Try also with a custom domain (point anything at 127.0.0.1, like https://example.com, via /etc/hosts)

The command spits out a readme file, but it's not really necessary.

Note: It's expected to get a cautionary message from the browser when accessing since it's a self-signed certificate.

PS: This assumes a normal and fresh-enough install the LAMP stack via `tasksel install lamp-server`

Comment: `a2ensite` and `a2enmod` ("apache2 enable site/module") have been around for a long time, even in Ubuntu 8.04 which was released in 2008! Your answer seems OK.